# Barchart's size changes over changing Tabs in AchartEngine

Tags: android, tabs, size, bar-chart, achartengine

i had an Activity with three bar charts and some TextViews, charts were fine in sizes and colors, but today after i've added TabHost and two more Tabs in my Activity the chart's size changes sometimes(not always) over changing Tabs.it's not changing when my Activity created or when i'm going from third tab to my first(Chart's Tab) it happen's in transition between tab number two to one(i have two ListViews in my second tab)! any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do a `renderer.setInScroll(true);` in order to avoid such unusual repaints.

Comment: Thank you Dan,i was waiting for you to answer ;) and can you explain why this happens?

Comment: It's a rendering issue. When you embed your chart inside a component like a ScrollView or a Tab, you have to call this method.